# Is it possible to use Flask-MySQLdb extension in the webpage deployed using render.com?

Tags: python, flask, flask-mysql, freesqldatabase

I want to deploy a website using flask. I used Planetscale to create a SQL database server before, but it only allows one free database. I found Flask-MySQLdb extension, but I am not sure if this extension will work as a SQL server on the web.